# How to find out what is causing network bottle neck - home network

Tags: home-networking

### Currently I have following Setup:

```
Fios router --> Netgear Wndr3400 (running Tomato) --> Netgear Wndr3700v2 (running DD-WRT)
                    |                                  |           |
                    |                                  |           |
               5 TB Linux Server                     HTPC     Other Living room devices
```

### Problem:

When I connect HTPC (Win8) to Wndr3400 directly I can copy files from the linux server at about 105 MBps. But as soon as I bring Wndr3700 in between, it drops to 45 MBps. It was worse before, when I had Wndr3700 running on OpenWrt.

Any idea how increase the copy speed [atleast within 80% of 105]? What could be the problem here?

[All connections are wired CAT5e]

Comment: Is the link between your Wndr3400 and Wndr3700v2 a Wireless link ?   (These figures sound very "pat" for wireless, you almost never get theoretical speed).  Also, is it possible you are using a different band to previously (eg 5 gig rather then 2.4 gig - your routers seem to be dual band), and are you using 20 or 40 mhz channels ? (Try shifting to 40mhz if using 20mhz)

Comment: All connections are wired.

Comment: Sounds like the Wndr3700 is either faulty or doing some packet handling on the way through and limiting the throughput.  Why don't you just replace it with an unmanaged switch ?

Comment: yes today I'm going to try that. I'm going to install a gigabit switch I borrowed from my friend.